# Firebase Local Emulator and Big-Query: Invalid Table Name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-tools

I don´t know if this is the right place to ask for help - but maybe someone could give me some tip:

I am trying to push my data from my project (running in local emulator suite) to big-query. Therefore I copied the extension code from ['https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export'](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export)

I added a cloud function to export my members-collection and when I create a new document in that collection, the big-query dataset and table are created, too.
but i get the following error message in my local console:

> "Error when mirroring data to BigQuery ApiError: Invalid table name:
> undefined.firestore_members.members_raw_changelog"

Could anyone give me a hint? is that "undefined" property the projectId? And why isn´t it set? If I do an

`console.log('PROJECT-ID:', await this.bq.getProjectId());`

in the initialize function it´s displayed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

This is coming due to an issue with a code in the function dependency. The code is written in snapshot.ts which tries to create a view using the table and datasetid. Along with it its also trying to pick the project id from the env . process.env.PROJECT_ID.My suggestion would be to set his as a property.  This the code :

```
return format(
  ` -- Retrieves the latest document change events for all live documents.
--   timestamp: The Firestore timestamp at which the event took place.
--   operation: One of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, IMPORT.
--   event_id: The id of the event that triggered the cloud function mirrored the event.
--   data: A raw JSON payload of the current state of the document.
--   document_id: The document id as defined in the Firestore database
SELECT
document_name,
document_id${groupByColumns.length > 0 ? "," : ""}
  ${groupByColumns.join(",")}
FROM (
  SELECT
    document_name,
    document_id,
    ${groupByColumns
  .map(
      (columnName) =>
        `FIRST_VALUE(${columnName})
        OVER(PARTITION BY document_name ORDER BY ${timestampColumnName} DESC)
        AS ${columnName}`,
  )
  .join(",")}${groupByColumns.length > 0 ? "," : ""}
    FIRST_VALUE(operation)
      OVER(PARTITION BY document_name ORDER BY ${timestampColumnName} DESC) = "DELETE"
      AS is_deleted
  FROM \`${process.env.PROJECT_ID}.${datasetId}.${tableName}\`
  ORDER BY document_name, ${timestampColumnName} DESC
)
WHERE NOT is_deleted
GROUP BY document_name, document_id${
      groupByColumns.length > 0 ? ", " : ""
```

}${groupByColumns.join(",")}`,